# Why i can add value to HKCU but not to HKCU\Environment without elevation?

Tags: python, registry

I'm executing the following simple code on Windows 8 that adds something to the `PATH` environment variable. Surprisingly, it fails with `error 5: access denied`. If `SetValueEx` points to `HKCU` instead of `HKCU\Environment` all works fine. I have checked permissions on `HKCU` and `HKCU\Environment` - they are same and user has full access. Why is access denied?

```
  hKey = _winreg.OpenKey( _winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Environment' )
  for i in itertools.count():
    try:
      sName, sData, nType = _winreg.EnumValue( hKey, i )
      if 'PATH' == sName:
        _winreg.SetValueEx( hKey, 'PATH', 0, nType, os.environ[ 'PATH' ] )
        break
    except WindowsError:
      raise "No 'PATH' in registry"
```

Comment: Try changing your `OpenKey` call to `_winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Environment', 0, _winreg.KEY_WRITE)` The default on the last parameter is read only access.

Comment: @Brian nope, same "access is denied". As i mentioned, i CAN write if i change parent key name - so it's something to do with "Environment" :(

Comment: Strange, sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: @Brian It seems my test was incorrect. I modified code second time with `_winreg.KEY_READ | _winreg.KEY_WRITE` and now all works! Please post your comment as an answer so i can accept it :)

Comment: Thanks for coming back and letting me know! Glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `OpenKey` call to

```
_winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Environment', 0, _winreg.KEY_READ | _winreg.KEY_WRITE)
```

The default on the last parameter is read only access according to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html).